# React Router DOM — How to include a navigation bar on every page?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have this code in my App.js component:

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar/>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                        <Route path="/about" component={About} />                         
                        <Route path="*" render={() => <Redirect to="/" />} />
                    </Switch>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Now I tried to include a Link component in one of my other components, but I figured out that the BrowserRouter has to be the root element of the App.js component, in order for that to work. Now I wonder how I would go about making it the route element, if I still want to include the navigation bar on every page.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should be able to just place it outside the `<Switch>` Component.

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <div>
        <Navbar/>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />                         
            <Route path="*" render={() => <Redirect to="/" />} />
        </Switch>
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Looking at my own project with react router it seems you need a wrapping `div` around `Navbar` and `Switch` since `BrowserRouter` expects a single child. Edited answer.