# Navbar is fixed in its position and is not moving with whole page in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I am learning Routes in ReactJS so I made a navbar with a bunch of page Routes now my navbar is not moving when i scroll in my page it stays in its place and only the route part of the page is moving which is problematic i am attaching the reference content with it.

**Code Snadbox:** [Environment Link Hosted here](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/pantharshit007/React-small-Projects/draft/thirsty-meninsky?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrzxzkjn00063569wpg430wc%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrzxzkjn000235691s120frn%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrzxzkjn000435696vqjoxvn%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrzxzkjn000535691l7athnc%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clrzxzkjn000235691s120frn%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrzxzkjm00013569cyohjh2o%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrzxzkjn000235691s120frn%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clrzxzkjm00013569cyohjh2o%2522%257D%252C%2522clrzxzkjn000535691l7athnc%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrzxzkjn000535691l7athnc%2522%257D%252C%2522clrzxzkjn000435696vqjoxvn%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrzxzkjn00033569zyimbg0s%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clrzxw2mj0064e7kccg974q3n%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrzxzkjn000435696vqjoxvn%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clrzxzkjn00033569zyimbg0s%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

**Here i scrolled but instead of NAVBAR moving upwards only the /signup page content moved upwards**
[image: This is what the scroll bar looks like]

**This is how it should look like where NAVBAR also moved upward while its page content is scrolled**
[image: This is how it should Actually look like where Navbar will also move along with page when scrolling]

**App -> Navbar /Signup -> Template -> SignupForm**
[image: App.jsx]

**App.jsx**

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import Home from './pages/Home'
import Login from './pages/Login'
import Signup from './pages/Signup'
import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard'
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import PrivateRoute from './components/PrivateRoute'

function App() {

  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false) ;

  return (
    <div className="w-screen h-screen bg-richblack-900 flex flex-col overflow-x-hidden font-inter">
      <Navbar isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} setIsLoggedIn={setIsLoggedIn}/>

      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login setIsLoggedIn={setIsLoggedIn}/>} />
        <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup setIsLoggedIn={setIsLoggedIn}/>} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" element={
          <PrivateRoute isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}>
            <Dashboard/>
          </PrivateRoute>
        } />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

**Navbar.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import logo from '../assets/logo.png'
import {toast} from 'react-hot-toast'

function Navbar(props) {
  let isLoggedIn = props.isLoggedIn;
  let setIsLoggedIn = props.setIsLoggedIn;

  return (
    <div className='flex justify-between items-center w-11/12 max-w-[1160px] py-4 mx-auto '>

      <Link to='/'>
      {/* #BF40BF */}
        <img src={logo} alt="Logo" width={160} height={32} loading='lazy' className=''/>
      </Link>

      <nav>
        <ul className="text-richblack-100 flex gap-x-6">
          <li>
            <Link to="/"> Home</Link>
          </li>

          <li>
            <Link to="/"> About</Link>
          </li>

          <li>
          <Link to="/"> Contact</Link>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </nav>

      {/* button: Login-SignUp || LogOut-DashBoard */}
      <div className='flex items-center gap-x-4 '>
        {/* If you are Logged In */}
        { !isLoggedIn &&  
          <Link to="/login"> 
            <button className="bg-richblack-800 text-richblack-100 py-[8px] px-[12px] rounded-[8px] border-richblack-700"
            >Log In</button>
          </Link>
        }

        { !isLoggedIn &&
          <Link to="/signup"> 
            <button className="bg-richblack-800 text-richblack-100 py-[8px] px-[12px] rounded-[8px] border-richblack-700" 
            > Sign Up</button>
          </Link>
        }

        { isLoggedIn &&
          <Link to="/"> 
            <button className="bg-richblack-800 text-richblack-100 py-[8px] px-[12px] rounded-[8px] border-richblack-700"
            onClick={()=>{
              setIsLoggedIn(false);
              toast.success("LogOut Successfully!");
            }}>Log Out</button>
          </Link>
        }

        { isLoggedIn &&
          <Link to="/dashboard">  
            <button className="bg-richblack-800 text-richblack-100 py-[8px] px-[12px] rounded-[8px] border-richblack-700"
            >Dashboard</button>
          </Link>
        }

      </div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

**Signup.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import Template from '../components/Template'
import signupImg from '../assets/signup.png'

function Signup({setIsLoggedIn}) {
  return (
    <Template 
      tittle= "Join the millions learning to code with LearningHub for free"
      desc1="Build skills for today, tomorrow, and beyond."
      desc2="Education to future-proof your career."
      image={signupImg}
      formtype="signup"
      setIsLoggedIn={setIsLoggedIn}
    />
  )
}

export default Signup
```

**Template.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import framImage from '../assets/frame.png'
import LoginForm from './LoginForm'
import SignUpForm from './SignUpForm'
import {FcGoogle} from 'react-icons/fc'

function Template({tittle, desc1, desc2, image, formtype, setIsLoggedIn}) {
  return (
    <div className="flex justify-between w-11/12 max-w-[1160px] py-12 gap-x-12 gap-y-0 mx-auto overflow-x-hidden">
        <div className='w-11/12 max-w-[450px]' >
            <h1 className="text-richblack-5 font-semibold text-[1.875rem] leading-[2.375rem]">{tittle}</h1>
            <p className='text-[1.125rem] leading[1.625rem] mt-4' >
                <span className='text-richblack-100'>{desc1}</span><br></br>
                <span className='text-violet-500 italic'>{desc2}</span>
            </p>

            {/* form Type */}
            {formtype === "signup" ?
                (<SignUpForm setIsLoggedIn={setIsLoggedIn}/>):
                (<LoginForm setIsLoggedIn={setIsLoggedIn}/>) 
            }
            {/* Decoration */}
            <div className='flex w-full items-center my-4 gap-x-2'>
                <div className='h-[1px] bg-richblack-700 w-full'></div>
                <p className='text-richblack-700 font-medium leading-[1.375rem] '> OR</p>
                <div className='h-[1px] bg-richblack-700 w-full'></div>
            </div>

            <button className='flex w-full justify-center items-center rounded-[8px] font-medium text-richblack-100 border border-richblack-700 px-[12px] py-[8px] gap-x-2 mt-6'>
                <FcGoogle/>
                <p>Sign Up with Google</p>
            </button>
            
        </div>

        <div className='relative w-11/12 max-w-[450px] '>
            {/* front image */}
            <img src={image} alt="front-img" width={558} height={504} loading='lazy'
            className='absolute -top-4 right-4'/>
            {/* bg image */}
            <img src={framImage} alt="bg-frame" width={558} height={504} loading='lazy'/>
        </div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Template
```

**SignUpForm.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import {AiOutlineEye, AiOutlineEyeInvisible} from 'react-icons/ai'
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'
import {toast} from 'react-hot-toast'

function SignUpForm({setIsLoggedIn}) {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState({
        firstName: '', 
        lastName: '', 
        email: '', 
        password: '', 
        confirmPassword: ''
    })
    const [showPassword1, setShowPassword1] = React.useState(false);
    const [showPassword2, setShowPassword2] = React.useState(false);
    const [accountType, setAccountType] = React.useState("student");

    function changeHandler(event) {
        setFormData((prevData) =>({
            ...prevData,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        }))
    }

    function submitHandler(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        if (formData.password != formData.confirmPassword) {
            toast.error('Password must be same!')
        }else{
            setIsLoggedIn(true);
            navigate('/dashboard');
            toast.success('Account Created!')
        }
        /*const accountData ={
            ...formData,
            accountType
        }
        console.log("printing account Info...");
        console.log(accountData);*/
    }

  return (
    <div >

        {/* Student / Instructor Tab */}
        <div className='flex bg-richblack-800 p-1 gap-x-1 my-6 rounded-full max-w-max transition-all duration-200 ease-in-out'>
            <button className={`${accountType === 'student' ?
                "bg-richblack-900 text-richblack-5 " :
                "bg-transparent text-richblack-200 "} 
                py-2 px-5 rounded-full transition-all duration-200 `}
            onClick= { ()=> setAccountType("student")}>
                Student
            </button>

            <button className={`${accountType === 'instructor' ?
                "bg-richblack-900 text-richblack-5 " :
                "bg-transparent text-richblack-200 "} 
                py-2 px-5 rounded-full transition-all duration-200 `}
            onClick= { ()=> setAccountType("instructor")}>
                Instructor
            </button>
        </div>

        <form onSubmit={submitHandler} className='flex flex-col w-full gap-y-4 mt-6 ml-1'>
            {/* firstName lastName */}
            <div className='flex gap-x-4'>
                <label className='w-full relative'>
                    <p className='text-[0.875rem] text-richblack-5 mb-1 leading-[1.375rem]'>
                        First Name <sup className='text-pink-200'>
                            *</sup></p>
                    <input 
                        type="text"
                        required
                        name="firstName"
                        placeholder="First Name"
                        value={formData.firstName}
                        onChange={changeHandler }
                        className='w-full bg-richblack-800 rounded-[0.5rem] text-richblack-5 p-[12px]'/>
                </label>
            
                <label className='w-full relative'>
                    <p className='text-[0.875rem] text-richblack-5 mb-1 leading-[1.375rem]'>
                        Last Name <sup className='text-pink-200'>
                            *</sup></p>
                    <input 
                        type="text"
                        required
                        name="lastName"
                        placeholder="Last Name"
                        value={formData.lastName}
                        onChange={changeHandler }
                        className='w-full bg-richblack-800 rounded-[0.5rem] text-richblack-5 p-[12px]'/>
                </label>
            </div>

             {/* email */}
             <label className='w-full relative'>
                    <p className='text-[0.875rem] text-richblack-5 mb-1 leading-[1.375rem]'>
                    Email Address <sup className='text-pink-200'>
                        *</sup></p>
                <input 
                    type="email"
                    required
                    name="email"
                    placeholder="Enter email address"
                    value={formData.email}
                    onChange={changeHandler }
                    className='w-full bg-richblack-800 rounded-[0.5rem] text-richblack-5 p-[12px]'/>
            </label>

            {/* create Pass and confirm Pass */}
            <div className='flex gap-x-4'>
                <label className='w-full relative'>
                    <p className='text-[0.875rem] text-richblack-5 mb-1 leading-[1.375rem]'>Create Password <sup className='text-pink-200'>
                        *</sup></p>
                    <input 
                        required
                        type={showPassword1 ? ("text") : ("password")} 
                        placeholder='Enter password' 
                        name='password' 
                        value={formData.password} 
                        onChange={changeHandler}
                        className='w-full bg-richblack-800 rounded-[0.5rem] text-richblack-5 p-[12px]'/>

                        <span className='absolute right-3 top-[38px] cursor-pointer '
                        onClick={() => setShowPassword1(!showPassword1)}>
                            {showPassword1 ? (<AiOutlineEye fontSize={24} fill='#AFB2bf'/>) : (<AiOutlineEyeInvisible fontSize={24} fill='#AFB2bf'/>)}
                        </span>
                </label>

                <label className='w-full relative'>
                    <p className='text-[0.875rem] text-richblack-5 mb-1 leading-[1.375rem]'>Confirm Password <sup className='text-pink-200'>
                        *</sup></p>
                    <input 
                        required
                        type={showPassword2 ? ("text") : ("password")} 
                        placeholder='Confirm password' 
                        name='confirmPassword' 
                        value={formData.confirmPassword} 
                        onChange={changeHandler}
                        className='w-full bg-richblack-800 rounded-[0.5rem] text-richblack-5 p-[12px]'/>

                        <span className='absolute right-3 top-[38px] cursor-pointer '
                        onClick={() => setShowPassword2(!showPassword2)}>
                            {showPassword2 ? (<AiOutlineEye fontSize={24} fill='#AFB2bf'/>) : (<AiOutlineEyeInvisible fontSize={24} fill='#AFB2bf'/>)}
                        </span>
                </label>
            </div>

            <button className='bg-yellow-50 rounded-[8px] font-medium text-richblack-900 px-[12px] py-[8px] mt-6'>
                Create Account</button>
            
        </form>
        
    </div>
  )
}

export default SignUpForm
```

I tried using methods which i can find online but none work. Do comment if you also encounter similar problem or any thread.

Comment: show your global css can u replicate this sandbox?

Comment: @SarimAhmed I added just now try checking it out

Comment: not able to access

Comment: I think your answer relate to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781056/react-router-dom-how-to-include-a-navigation-bar-on-every-page

Comment: @SarimAhmed i don't know how to share for the public since its my first time using it but I did add a hosted link